# Zurb Foundation 3: vertical align form elements to middle in row

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, zurb-foundation

**EDIT:** I am using Zurb Foundation 3, so the text-inputs might be special

I have a form which consists of a few rows with identical fields. In each row there are different types of elements, some text inputs, some buttons, a checkbox...

All those elements have different heights and I want them to be vertically centered in respect to each other. This is my code so far:

```
<tr>
    <td class="four middle"><input type="text".../></td>
    <td class="two middle"><input type="checkbox".../></td>
    <td class="two middle"><input.../></td>
    <td class="four middle"><a href="#" class="button small">Button</a></td>
</tr>
```

In my CSS I specified:

```
.middle { vertical-align: middle !important; }
```

This does indeed center the checkbox and the button, but not the text inputs, which seem to remain top-aligned. I have also tried some variations with divs instead of a table, but without luck. What am I missing?

Comment: the css and html code are correct, i tested them on FF and all the inputs are correctly centered. check if the style is correctly applied using firebug for example

Comment: Are you using Zurb Foundation 3? I forgot to mention that in the text and only mentioned it in the title of my question...

Comment: nope, indeed i just triyed with the css and html in your question body. Sorry

Comment: You may need to inspect the CSS property line-height being applied to the TDs and the INPUT elements. I have not found vertical-align to perform as you might expect in all cases. Not sure if it is me (probably) or the browser implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is being added to the input

```
margin:0 0 12px 0;
```

just set the bottom margin to 0 or add the 12px margin to the top, its up to you